# value of dynamically created editext not getting stored

Tags: java, android

Hi i have been working on an app where i have a plus button and onclick of that plus button i'm inflating  a layout. Every time user clicks on plus button a new layout is created now i'm adding the data from editext to database and so far every thing is working however my problem is that only last editext value is getting stored in database i have two editext in layout and i'm using retrofit for api call.
So please if someone could help me here

**Edit:debugged the code and maintained a separate arraylist and it returns the proper size however when i use a for loop for sending data as you can see in the second piece of code only last data is getting repeated **

Here is the method to inflate the layout

```
 public void makedifferentEditText() {
        try {

                View secondchild = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.update_extra_links_layout, null);
                final LinearLayout update_extra_links_layout = (LinearLayout) secondchild.findViewById(R.id.update_extra_links_layout);
                customtextTitle = (CustomEditTextThin) secondchild.findViewById(R.id.google_edit_link);
                customeditTextLink = (CustomEditTextThin) secondchild.findViewById(R.id.facebook_edit_link);
                google_tilte.add(customtextTitle);
                google_link.add(customeditTextLink);
                Log.e("title",google_tilte.toString());
                Log.e("link",google_link.toString());
                //String customLink = customeditTextLink.getText().toString();
                AppCompatImageView removeimage = (AppCompatImageView) secondchild.findViewById(R.id.icon_remove_link);
                //arrayLink.add(customLink);
                //arrayLink.add(customtextTitle.getText().toString());

//            for(int i=0;i<200;i++){
//                customLink[i] = customeditTextLink.getText().toString();
//                customGoogleLink[i] = customeditTextLink.getText().toString();
//            }
                eexId = (TextView) secondchild.findViewById(R.id.eeid);

                rAlign.addView(update_extra_links_layout);
                removeimage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        rAlign.removeView(update_extra_links_layout);
                    }
                });

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

and Here is how i'm getting the data to send

```
if(google_link!=null && google_link.size()>0) {
                    for(int j=0;j<google_link.size();j++) {
                        arrayTitle.add(google_link.get(j).getText().toString());
                        Log.e("array", arrayTitle.toString());
                            if (customtextTitle != null && customeditTextLink != null) {
                                if (arrayTitle != null) {
                                    for (String link : arrayTitle) {
                                        ExtraLinksObject links4 = new ExtraLinksObject();
                                        String othergoogleTitle = customtextTitle.getText().toString();
                                        String othergooglelink = link;//customeditTextLink.getText().toString();
                                        String googleId = eexId.getText().toString();
                                        links4.setLink(othergooglelink);
                                        links4.setTitle(othergoogleTitle);
                                        links4.setExID(googleId);

                                        extraLinks.add(links4);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Can you try replacing `if(customtextTitle!=null && customeditTextLink!=null)` with  `if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(customtextTitle) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(customeditTextLink)) `

Comment: yes i can but my probelm is that only last created editext value is getting stored in database

Comment: hey sreekant can help me out.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally i was able to solve it on my own by making an arraylist of editext and looping it through.
I hope this helps someone in future

```
if (google_link != null && google_link.size() > 0) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < google_link.size(); j++) {
                            /*arrayTitle.add(google_link.get(j).getText().toString());
                            Log.e("array", arrayTitle.toString());*/

                            ExtraLinksObject links4 = new ExtraLinksObject();

                            String othergoogleTitle = google_tilte.get(j).getText().toString();//customtextTitle.getText().toString();
                            String othergooglelink = google_link.get(j).getText().toString();//customeditTextLink.getText().toString()
                            String googleId = extId.get(j).getText().toString();//eexId.getText().toString();
                            links4.setLink(othergooglelink);
                            links4.setTitle(othergoogleTitle);
                            links4.setExID(googleId);

                            extraLinks.add(links4);

                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score -1):

you can get one by one child for view and add to DB

```
for(int i = 0; i < rAlign.getChildCount();i++) {
    View secondchild = rAlign.getChildAt(i);
    customtextTitle = (CustomEditTextThin) secondchild.findViewById(R.id.google_edit_link);
    customeditTextLink = (CustomEditTextThin) secondchild.findViewById(R.id.facebook_edit_link);
    eexId = (TextView) secondchild.findViewById(R.id.eeid);
    if (customtextTitle != null && customeditTextLink != null) {
        ExtraLinksObject links4 = new ExtraLinksObject();
        String othergoogleTitle = customtextTitle.getText().toString();
        String othergooglelink = customeditTextLink.getText().toString();
        String googleId = eexId.getText().toString();
        links4.setLink(othergooglelink);
        links4.setTitle(othergoogleTitle);
        links4.setExID(googleId);
        extraLinks.add(links4);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hii Vinay i tried your code and when i debugged it the code went into infinite loop

Comment: for loop is repeat `rAlign.getChildCount()` times only

Comment: yes i added for getChilcount only but it went into infinite for loop

Comment: not possible, please log value of `i` inside loop and verify

Comment: i logged the value of i as well as debugged it the code goes into infinite for loop..